# axios does not work with while fetch does

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, axios, fetch-api

i want to get data (array) from /{url} and i tried this code

```
// Fetch the list on first mount
componentDidMount() {
this.getList();
}

// Retrieves the list of items from the Express app
getList = () => {

fetch('/main')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(list => this.setState({ list }))
}
```

this is working fine but then i decided to switch to axios and tried literally same code

```
  // Fetch the list on first mount
componentDidMount() {
this.getList();
}

 // Retrieves the list of items from the Express app
 getList = () => {
 axios.get('/main')
.then(res=> res.json())
.then(list => this.setState({list}))

}
```

but it did not worked and gave me error in this line:  .then(res=> res.json())
so i do not know what is problem if anyone knows the clue i will be glad if you tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Fetch the list on first mount
componentDidMount() {
  this.getList();
}

// Retrieves the list of items from the Express app
getList = () => {
 axios.get('/main')
 .then(res=> res.data)
 .then(list => this.setState({list}))
 .catch(error => this.setState({error: error.message}))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because axios has different response, instead of `res.json()` return data already like : `return res.data` or pass it to state directly something like

```
getList = () => {
 axios.get('/main')
   .then(res=> this.setState({list: res.data}))
```

Comment: it worked but can you tell my why? what type of response does axios have?

Comment: response from axios is data object (wrapper with lots of additional data) to access data served from express server you need to access `data` inside of taht object like `response.data`

Comment: and what type of instance is response from fetch?

Comment: here check axios docs https://github.com/axios/axios and this about fetch. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data ...

Answer (score 2):

i would recommend some changes in your design, as im using axios successfully in many projects, its not a requirement but it helps and is working very reliable:

**Create a service like api.js**

```html
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://my.api.url/`
});
```

Then you can use it like this

```html
import API from '../Services/api'; // this is your service you created before

LoadStats = async event => {
    try {
        var response = await API.get('api/targetroute');
        if (response.data != null) {
            this.setState({
                stats: {
                    mydata: response.data
                }
            });
            console.log('Receiving result: '+JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR: '+error)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, as i noticed you modified code to async, but i thought axios was already async with Promise API

Comment: axios is always returning a promise so its always async the question here is how to handle the promise in your code.

there are several ways to go, using subscriptions or

handling promises with then /catch or using async decorator are all handling promises with a different software design.

i usually prefer using the async decorator as im coming from c# and i like the programming flow it allows.. of course sometimes its better to just subscribe to the event

i personally think promise chaining then / catch is a nogo as its an absolute mess, but this is my personal opinion

Comment: if you ask me there is no need for baseUrl, (at least in my case) because i am not using it and it still not blocking Cross Origin Request

Comment: i like it clear and beauty so by consuming several api's / routes / services i only have to change the base url servers change etc..
usually you have several routes per api to consume so overall all routes have a base url

of course this is a personal design thing, do it how you like :)

what do you mean by ...still not blocking CORS ?

Comment: oh i forgot to tell that i am using cors module in server side but i think it would be still fine if i don't have it yeah it does not block CORS

Comment: i'll be glad if you will be able to help me with question this is really annoying 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167140/nodejs-send-200-status-code-2-times-if-condition-is-true

Comment: well requests from clients get  blocked if they run against Same Origin Policy and there is no CORS Exception defined on the server side.. overall its a browser / client security thing.
Before a request is sent (from the browser / client) the browser is sending an preflight Options Request to check if a request is allowed by CORS.. (if its not SOP)

in most local cases you can install a cors browser plugin for development purposes. in production you define CORS on the serverside.

this does not affect the software design by using a service and base url

Comment: Hey @Jake i took a look but just at this moment there was a good answer by somebody. if you have further questions, just let us know :)

Comment: i upvoted you and your comment too, maybe there is problem in Stackoverflow