# NodeJS - send 200 status code 2 times if condition is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I to send data 2 times to client but only send second data to client if some condition is true for example: if some variable exists (from middleware, in my case: req.userId which is not always expected since req.userId is decoded id from jwt token so if token exists, req.userId exists too.

I am validating user in that way, if user has authenticated s/he has token and I send additional data, otherwise I should send data that is visible for everyone) send header to client with 200 status code (I mean that header is not for error) and continue code execution and outside of that if statement there is second header to send also with 200 status code, but if condition is false skip that condition and just send second header which is sent in every case, and client side (react js) check if that data exists and then set it to state or do whatever to prevent undefined variables, client side validation is easy I already did it but because of my buggy code I got undefined.

Anyway, I knew it and it was planned that i would get undefined without checking, so problem is not in client side, it's in server side and here's problem: my code only sends header which is first in code here is my code

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  var data = { foo: "bar", foo1: "bar1" };

  if (req.userId) {
    const user = await User.findById({ _id: req.userId }, "-password").lean();

    res.status(200).send({ name: user.username });
  }

  return res.status(200).send({ data: JSON.stringify(data) });
});
```

So if I write `return res.status(200).send({data: JSON.stringify(data)})` first it does not send send data object (neither not name) but when i authenticate and create req.userId it sends data object (not name), but if i first write condition it does not sends anything at first but when i authenticate and create req.userId it sends name (not data object), i am really confused and don't know why is this happening

Here is my react code if it matters:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get("/api/main")
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({ name: data.name });

      alert(data.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response.data.message);
      }
    });
}
```

Since I am using componentDidMount it should send data object when page content loads

**THANKS!**

Comment: First, you need rethink this decision. You should only respond once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reply twice for a single request. But you can manage the way you answer differently, for example :

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  var data = { foo: "bar", foo1: "bar1" };

  if (req.userId) {
    const user = await User.findById({ _id: req.userId }, "-password").lean();

    data.name = user.username;
  }

  return res.status(200).send({ data: JSON.stringify(data) });
});
```

Comment: i agree to this answer.. there is not much to add. http requests are a bit like fire and forget and as Serge K. said you can not reply twice, its all about how you handle your response. If you have further questions, just let us know! Cheers mate

Comment: it seems correct answer, just about to try the code and i will let you know the result

Comment: oh nothing to worry, it works thanks i just got problem in my client side thanks!

Comment: nice, 
have fun mate

Comment: @xzesstence but there is still some problem

Comment: the code does only sends data when user is authenticated

Comment: ok then check for authentication (sorry pseudo code)
if(user !== null) / (authenticated === true) {
return res.status(200)
} else {
return res.status(401)
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190039/discussion-between-jake-and-xzesstence).